# Using multiple variables in main -- While Loop not stops

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop, python-turtle

### Coding a graphing calculator

Two of the variables I use that require input are **equation** and **z**.

Both variables are declared in main() function and passed as arguments to classes `Equation` and `Pointer`.

However when I run the code the only thing that actually happens is that runs until the `Graph` and never reaches `Intercepts`.

What is it missing?

Additionally if Plot is called before Equation than it runs and Equation isn't.

### main file

```
from classes_test import Equation
from classes_test import Pointer

def main():
    global equation
    equation = input('enter expression')
    global z
    z = input('enter plotting gap')

    
    
    Function = Equation(equation, z)
    Graph = Function.grapher()
    
    
    
    
    Intercepts = Pointer(equation, z)
    Plot = Intercepts.calculate()
    print("this should show it is working")
    
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Class file

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 300, 300
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.setworldcoordinates(-100,-100,100,100)


class Equation:
    def __init__(self, equation, z):
        self.equation = equation
        self.z = z
    
    def grapher(self):
        x= -150
        graph = Turtle()
        xposaxis = Turtle()
        xnegaxis = Turtle()
        yposaxis = Turtle()
        ynegaxis = Turtle()
        xposaxis.speed(0)
        xnegaxis.speed(0)
        yposaxis.speed(0)
        ynegaxis.speed(0) 
        xposaxis.forward(300)
        xnegaxis.setheading(180)
        xnegaxis.forward(300)
        yposaxis.setheading(90)
        yposaxis.forward(300)
        ynegaxis.setheading(270)
        ynegaxis.forward(300)
        xposaxis.ht()
        xnegaxis.ht()
        yposaxis.ht()
        ynegaxis.ht()
        graph.speed(0)
        graph.clear()
        graph.penup()
        graph.st()
        while True:
                try:
                    while x <= 150:
                        y = eval(self.equation)
                        print(x,y)
                        graph.goto(x,y)
                        graph.pendown()
                        x  += float(self.z)
                        if x > 150:
                            graph.ht()
                except ZeroDivisionError:
                        print("error")
                        x += float(self.z)
                    
        return 

class Pointer:
    def __init__ (self, equation, z):
        self.equation = equation
        self.z = z
        
    

    def calculate(self):
        x = -150
        plots = Turtle()
        plots.speed(0)
        plots.clear()
        plots.ht()
        plots.penup()
        plots.shape("circle")
        plots.pensize(3)
        while True:
                try:
                    while x <= 150:
                        y = eval(self.equation)
                        if y == 0:
                            plots.pencolor('red')
                            plots.st()
                            plots.pendown()
                            plots.forward(0.1)
                            plots.penup()
                            print('test')
                            plots.write((x,y), move=False, font=("Arial", 8, "normal"))
                            plots.ht()

                        
                        
                        
                        x  += float(self.z)
                        if x > 150:
                            plots.ht()
                except ZeroDivisionError:
                        plots.pencolor('green')
                        plots.st()
                        plots.pendown()
                        plots.forward(0.1)
                        plots.penup()
                        plots.write((x), "is a vertical asymptote", move=False, font=("Arial", 8, "normal"))
                        plots.ht()
                        x += float(self.z)
        return
```

Please let me know what is missing so I can get it to both graph and plot at the same time.

Comment: Both your methods appear to be infinite loops that never terminate. If they don't terminate, the script won't continue.

Comment: I think you need to give input and output samples for more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running into is with your first While loop, rather than the input variables. Without seeing input and output samples, I can only assume when you say that whichever you call first runs and the second does not that you mean that it runs correctly.  In that case we can discount your variables as the cause of the issue.

You are using "while True" without a break statement inside that loop.  So the loop in whatever class method you call first gets stuck in an infinite loop.
The answer depends on what you are trying to accomplish with the while True.  If the reason is (as I suspect) that you are trying to keep the first graph active while the plot is drawn in the same space, you can solve your problem by simply removing the while True from both class methods, returning the Turtle object from one and then passing it to the second draw method as a parameter.  That is the simple fix.

A cleaner solution would be to combine your classes and instantiate the Turtle object in your **init** as a self.turtle or whatever you wish to call it.  Then both your graph and plot functions could make use of the same resource.  As above, without the need for a while True.

If the reason for your while True is some other reason that my assumption, you will need to find what you want to break you out of your loop and either "break" on that condition, or if it's buried in your 2nd while loop (where it would only break you out of the 2nd while and not the 1st) set your return statement there.

Answer (score 0):

There are many design issue with the code,  but for the error you mentioned, try the following code.

```
class Equation:
    def __init__(self, equation, z):
        self.equation = equation
        self.z = z
    
    def grapher(self):
        x= -150
        graph = Turtle()
        xposaxis = Turtle()
        xnegaxis = Turtle()
        yposaxis = Turtle()
        ynegaxis = Turtle()
        xposaxis.speed(0)
        xnegaxis.speed(0)
        yposaxis.speed(0)
        ynegaxis.speed(0) 
        xposaxis.forward(300)
        xnegaxis.setheading(180)
        xnegaxis.forward(300)
        yposaxis.setheading(90)
        yposaxis.forward(300)
        ynegaxis.setheading(270)
        ynegaxis.forward(300)
        xposaxis.ht()
        xnegaxis.ht()
        yposaxis.ht()
        ynegaxis.ht()
        graph.speed(0)
        graph.clear()
        graph.penup()
        graph.st()
        while True:
                try:
                    while x <= 150:
                        y = eval(self.equation)
                        print(x,y)
                        graph.goto(x,y)
                        graph.pendown()
                        x  += float(self.z)
                        if x > 150:
                            graph.ht()
                except ZeroDivisionError:
                        print("error")
                        x += float(self.z)
                
            break                    
        return 

class Pointer:
    def __init__ (self, equation, z):
        self.equation = equation
        self.z = z
        
    

    def calculate(self):
        x = -150
        plots = Turtle()
        plots.speed(0)
        plots.clear()
        plots.ht()
        plots.penup()
        plots.shape("circle")
        plots.pensize(3)
        while True:
                try:
                    while x <= 150:
                        y = eval(self.equation)
                        if y == 0:
                            plots.pencolor('red')
                            plots.st()
                            plots.pendown()
                            plots.forward(0.1)
                            plots.penup()
                            print('test')
                            plots.write((x,y), move=False, font=("Arial", 8, "normal"))
                            plots.ht()

                        
                        
                        
                        x  += float(self.z)
                        if x > 150:
                            plots.ht()
                except ZeroDivisionError:
                        plots.pencolor('green')
                        plots.st()
                        plots.pendown()
                        plots.forward(0.1)
                        plots.penup()
                        plots.write((x), "is a vertical asymptote", move=False, font=("Arial", 8, "normal"))
                        plots.ht()
                        x += float(self.z)
                break
        return
```

> If this doesn't solved the issue then add the error you get or the actual behavior or the issue.

PS. Note, I just try to find where the error is however the script has some pitfall, for instance one function does't too many things.

One function is supposed to perform more or less one task (when is possible), better to split this in more separate function delegating each one task.

Is easier to find the errors and debug.
Also because a function has a name, the name its self explained what the function does, hence more understandable what the whole script does too.